# Importar várias tabelas do excel ao mesmo tempo

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Desejo importar 27 tabelas Excel para o R sem precisar digitar 27 vezes o comando de importação já, que os nomes das tabelas vão de `tab101` a `tab127`. Tentei dessa forma, mas ficou com erro:

```
library(readxl)
n = c()
for (i in 1:27){ # fazendo um vetor com os nomes dos arquivos
a = "tab"
a = paste(a, 100+i, sep = "")
a = paste(a, ".xls", sep = "")
n[i] = a
}
t =lapply(n, read_excel) #aplicando read_excel para importar cada arquivo e  
#juntando tudo em uma lista
```

Até aí achei que estava com sucesso. Está criada a lista de 27 elementos, mas quando eu peço para mostrar o primeiro elemento da lista aparece o seguinte:

```
t[1]  
[[1]]
Error in gsub(ansi_regex, "", string, perl = TRUE) : 
 input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
```

Sendo que se eu chamar o `str(t)` ele mostra que os dados foram importados corretamente. Não estou sabendo acessar cada elemento da lista. Mas o foco mesmo é conseguir importar todas as tabelas de uma vez, não precisa necessariamente criar uma lista com elas. Eu tentei fazer só com o for, colocando o `read_table(a)` dentro, mas não fazia nada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, vamos criar um vetor com os nomes de todos os teus arquivos `.xls`:

```
arquivos <- list.files()
arquivos <- arquivos[grep(".xls", arquivos)]
```

A primeira linha acima lista todos os arquivos no teu diretório de trabalho. Como podem haver arquivos com extensão diferente de `.xls`, a segunda linha substitui o conteúdo do vetor original com os nomes apenas dos arquivos que possuam a string `.xls` em algum lugar de seu nome.

Em seguida, é só rodar um `for` utilizando o comando `assign`. Este comando vai fazer com que sejam criados objetos dentro do workspace do `R`. Estes objetos terão o nome e o conteúdo dos teus arquivos `.xls`:

```
library(readxl)
for (j in arquivos){
  assign(j, read_excel(j))
}
```

Por exemplo, se os arquivos se chamam `tab101.xls`, ..., `tab127.xls`, os objetos dentro do `R` serão criados com os nomes `tab101.xls`, ..., `tab127.xls`.

Se tu não desejar que os objetos lidos dentro do `R` tenham o sufixo `.xls` (que é uma preocupação apenas estética), basta rodar o código abaixo:

```
for (j in arquivos){
  assign(strsplit(j, split="\\.")[[1]][1], read_excel(j))
}
```

Assim, os objetos terão nomes como `tab101`, ..., `tab127`, sem a extensão `.xls`.

Comment: Muito obrigada, Marcus. Consegui resolver de outra forma, mas a sua ficou bem mais sucinta e direta, além de me apresentar alguns comandos novos. Muito bom

Comment: Marcus, e se algumas planilhas tiver vários worksheets. Como importar todas as planilhas e todos os worksheets que elas possuem?

Comment: Érika, coloque a sua solução aqui também. veja, read_excel(path, sheet = 1), então deve dar para variar o sheet com um segundo for.